# trouble reading from .txt and writing it on a text box

Tags: c++, forms, file, textbox

i'm trying to read from a .txt file and write it on a listBox (windows forms application)
What i want to read is of type double and i don't know why but after the dot on the number, it no longer reads and transfers it to another variable! 
Also, it writes something twice, it's like it's doing this cycle twice and showing the same info, when it shouldn't

here's the part of the code i think might have the mistake:

```
char empresam[11];
             int tipom;
             int codigom;
             double valorm;
             int Data_lev[5];
             int Data_arm[5];
             CData DActual;
             int Data_actual[3];
             bool mercadoria=false;
             int precom;
             Data_actual[0]=DActual.Rano();
             Data_actual[1]=DActual.Rmes();
             Data_actual[2]=DActual.Rdia();

             //leitura do ficheiro

             facturacao.peek();
             while(!facturacao.eof()){
                 facturacao.getline(empresam, 11);
                 empresam[10]='\0';
                 facturacao >> tipom >> codigom;
                 facturacao>>Data_lev[0]>>Data_lev[1]>>Data_lev[2]>>Data_lev[3]>>Data_lev[4];
                 facturacao>>Data_arm[0]>>Data_arm[1]>>Data_arm[2]>>Data_arm[3]>>Data_arm[4];
                 facturacao >> valorm;
                 facturacao >>precom;
                 cin.ignore();
                 facturacao.peek();


                 if(Data_lev[0]==Data_actual[0] && Data_lev[1]==Data_actual[1] && Data_lev[2]==Data_actual[2]){
                     mercadoria=true;
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->BeginUpdate();
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add ("Código de empresa");
                     //converter char* para string ^
                     String^ strempresa = gcnew String(empresam);
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add(strempresa);
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add("Códido de armazenamento");
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add(codigom);
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add("Mercadoria do tipo");
                     switch(tipom){
                     case 1: {ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add("Contentor 12 x 2,3 m");break;};
                     case 2: {ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add("Contentor 6 x 2,3 m");break;};
                     case 3: {ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add("Palete 120 x 80 cm");break;};
                     case 4: {ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add("Palete 60 x 80 cm");break;};
                     }
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add("Valor declarado");
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add(valorm);
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add( "Armazenado na data");
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add ("Data");
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add("Valor pago");
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->Items->Add(precom);
                     ffacturacaod->listBox1->EndUpdate();

                 }


                 facturacao.close();
```

Comment: Your code formatting is very hard to read - if you're using visual studio, press ctrl + a to select all, and then, holding control, press K then F and release control. Command is ctrl+KF. That will autoformat for you.

Comment: Your code looks like C++/CLI or C++/CX. Can you confirm which language and platform you're using?

Comment: Is it easier now? @ChristianStewart

Comment: @Dai  i have to use c++ and I have to produce a VC++ project. i'm not really sure what is it that you're asking. I've just started programming

Comment: i've found out why it didn't read the entire number. int precom should be double precom but it still shows the data twice

Comment: well, besides declaring as int instead of double, i see that i do cin.ignore instead of facturacao.ignore().


but when i have to read twice, it doesn't work. it doesn't delete the data that was already on the variables and shows the same information